# Is the four move checkmate the fastest way to win a game of chess?

Tags: chess

Is the four move check mate `(1. e4 e5 2.Qf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Bc5?? 4.Qxf7#)` the fastest way to win a game of chess, or is there a quicker way?

Comment: FYI: The checkmate you describe is known as the `scholar's mate`

Comment: @ColinD - Yes, although a slightly unusual move order. The OP has Qf3 on move 2, which is easily countered by Black's Nf6. This is the [Napoleon Opening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_Opening).

Comment: This question was recently asked on chess.stackexchange: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/minimum-moves-to-checkmate

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a quicker checkmate called the [Fool's Mate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fool%27s_mate) which only takes 2 moves.

The moves that demonstrate the checkmate are:

```
1. f3 e5
2. g4 Qh4#
```

Comment: Also, of course, the fastest mate for White is in 2 1/2 moves (rather than the 3 1/2 given in the opening post) by making a 'blank' move and then following this in reverse: 1. a3 f6, 2. e4 g5, 3. Qh5#.

Comment: So 'one move' means 'a move for White then a move for Black'. I did not know that.

Comment: Can this be edited to show the moves on the board itself like some questions on Chess Stack exchange?

Answer (score 5):

Fool's mate is the quickest way to *mate*, not *win*. Technically the fastest way to win is for your opponent to resign on the first move or for them to lose on time (e.g. not show up but their clock is running).

Comment: I'm not quite sure that your opponent running out of time could be called "fast" :-)

Comment: True @PhilipKendall. Depends whether there is a bar in the venue, in which case the time flies by...

Comment: Although the answer stands and is relevant to my question I feel this is being a tad Pedantic haha XD

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way for Black to mate is

```
1. f3 e5
2. g4 Qh4#
```

1.f4 is also possible so there are two versions of this.

There are more versions for a fast mate by White:

```
1. e4 g5
2. d4 f5
3. Qh5#
```

Coupled with this f, g pawn advances there is also another neat version
which takes the same amount of moves for White to mate:

```
1. e4 e5
2. Qh5 Ke7
3. Qxe5#
```

Thereby fastest white mate can happen in three moves (precisely 2½
moves) whereas fastest black mate can happen in two moves.